# Multi image upload issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He,
Im working on multi image upload, what im doing is on choosing images i display preview of all images then i submit all data.

**My HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="newimage" name="newimage" multiple="" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" class="inputfile" onchange="readURLNEW(this,'5');">
```

**My JS:**

```js
function readURLNEW(input,cnt) {
                         
                 if (input.files) {
                              
                     var dispimgcnt = $('.singleImageCanvasContainer').length;
                     
                     var filesAmount = input.files.length;
                     var total = filesAmount + dispimgcnt;
                       var imagesLoaded = 0;
                      if(total <= cnt)
                      {
                         $('.preloader').show();      
                        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                            
                             var j = 1; 
                         var reader = new FileReader();
                         reader.onload =  function (e) {      
                            var image = new Image();  
                            image.onload =  function (imageEvent) {   
                                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),  
                                    max_size = 500,// TODO : max size for a pic  
                                    width = image.width,  
                                    height = image.height;  
                                if (width > height) {  
                                    if (width > max_size) {  
                                        height *= max_size / width;  
                                        width = max_size;  
                                    }  
                                } else {  
                                    if (height > max_size) {  
                                        width *= max_size / height;  
                                        height = max_size;  
                                    }  
                                }  
                                canvas.width = width;  
                                canvas.height = height;  
                                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);  

                                var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');  

                       var blob = dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);        
                              
                    var icnt = dispimgcnt > 0 ? (dispimgcnt + j) : j;
                      var data = new FormData();
                      
                      data.append('file', blob);
                     
                    $.ajax({
                        url :  "tempsave.php",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        async:false, 
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(data) {  
                                                      if($('.singleImageCanvasContainer').length <= 0)
                                display = 'block';         
                            
                         var div = $("<div class='singleImageCanvasContainer pimage' id='singleImageCanvasContainer"+(icnt)+"' style='display: inline-block;position: relative;margin-right:5px;margin-top: 10px;' > <button type='button' class='singleImageCanvasCloseBtn' style='position:absolute;background:#61f573;border:none;font-size:1.2em;border-radius:50%;-webkit-appearance: none;padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px;left: 78%;'>"
                          +"<i class='fa fa-bars'></i>"
                        +"<div class='dropdown-content' style='display:none'><a href='#' class='main_pic' style='display:'>Set as main picture</a><a href='#' class='crop_pic'>Crop</a><a href='#' class='delete_pic'>Delete</a></div>"
                       +"</button><button type='button' class='singleImageCanvasMainBtn' style='display:"+display+";position:absolute;background:#61f573;border:none;font-size:1.2em;border-radius:50%;-webkit-appearance: none;padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px;display: '><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button>"
                        +"<img style='border-radius:20px; height: 150px;width: 150px;border:1px solid lightgray' src='"+data+"' class='file-img img-loading'></div>"
                       );
                      
                         $('div.imgcontainer').append(div); 
                           imagesLoaded++;

                            if(imagesLoaded == filesAmount){
                                allLoaded();
                            }
                          
                        },
                        error: function() {
                             $('.preloader').hide();
                          alert("Failed!");
                        }
                      });
                      j++;
                       }
                          
                            image.src = e.target.result; 
                    
                         };
                         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);

                        }
                    
                     }
                                             
                 }
              
     }
```

Using mobile network, the weird upload timing scenario on choosing images:

```
 1. if i choose five 5mb images at same time (server uploading time is 94seconds)
 2. if i choose four 5mb image first, then i choose one 5mb image separatly(server uploading time is 37 seconds)
 3. if i choose one 5mb image, then another 5mb image like this i choose five 5mb separatly then (server uploading time is 16 seconds)
```

did anyone faced this scenario? did i do anything wrong in js, because in php i just save images in folder and data in DB, so there is no issues in php side(its basic code only).

in js, i used render.onload and image.onload and ajax call, is there any issues lying there? please help!!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: JS problem because php code is basic

Comment: check my upload time scenario

Comment: Can you share the timing tab under the network tab with the request selected. (in the browser)

Comment: Why tag PHP if that's not the source of your issue and isn't even included in your question? I'll remove that tag from your question